# Is it okay to "hook" into a many-to-many relation table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I got 3 tables: Recipe R, Ingredient I and IngredientAmount IA

R and I got a many-to-many relation connection table.

Now, i need to chain IA to I, so that i know that fx a recipe needs potato (I) and the amount is 2 kg (IA)

Should i make a FK to I from IA or would it be okay to hook the IA FK into the many-to-many relation table between I and R?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it gets much easier if you do it the other way around

I would read it as this:

```
A recipe has a set of ingredient amounts
an ingredient amount has one ingredient
```

So that would mean you have a recipe table like

```
RecipeId Title
```

And an ingredient amount table that references a recipe as well as an ingredient via foreign keys for example

```
IngredientAmountId RecipeId IngredientId Amount
```

And the ingredient amounts finally reference the ingredient itself

```
IngredientId Title
```

So only a few one to many relationships (one recipe has many ingredient amounts, one ingredient can belong to many ingredient amounts) needed no many to many relationship imho.

### TL;DR

In your question you stated that you already "connected" recipes with ingredients, in my opinion this is flawed; there should really be a connection between recipe and ingredientamounts and another connection between ingredientamounts and ingredients.

Comment: That does make sense, thanks!

My thoughtprocess was that i need to be able to search for ingredients that is connected to the recipe, hence the connection between recipe and ingredient.

With your approach, wouldn't it be a bit tedious to get the associated ingredient?

Comment: Yea I understand, but finding out ingredients for each recipe does not become really hard with this because you still can join ;) for example `SELECT Ingredients.IngredientId FROM Recipes INNER JOIN IngredientAmounts ON Recipes.RecipeId = IngredientAmounts.RecipeId INNER JOIN Ingredients ON IngredientAmounts.IngredientId = Ingredients.IngredientId` so I would say, tedious? no! verbose? yes :D but easier to understand? also yes.

Comment: @rasmus glad I could help, gg :D

Comment: But, now i will get a load of duplicated ingredients, where as the many to many table from my design should prevent that.

Comment: @Rasmus no you get possibly duplicated ingredient amounts (that vary only on their RecipeId) from this not duplicated ingredients